# php libcouchbase exception straight after installation

Tags: php, couchbase

i have installed couchbase on ubuntu:

```
$ php -i | grep couchbase
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/couchbase.ini,
couchbase
couchbase support => enabled
libcouchbase version => 2.0.5
couchbase.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
couchbase.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
couchbase.compressor => none => none
couchbase.config_cache => no value => no value
couchbase.durability_default_poll_interval => 100000 => 100000
couchbase.durability_default_timeout => 40000000 => 40000000
couchbase.instance.persistent => On => On
couchbase.restflush => On => On
couchbase.serializer => php => php
couchbase.view_timeout => 75 => 75
```

i have also done this:

```
$ locate libevent.so
/opt/couchbase/lib/libevent.so
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/couchbase/lib
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/couchbase/lib
```

so now i try and run the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "", "default");
$cb->set("a", 101);
var_dump($cb->get("a"));
?>
```

but i get the following errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CouchbaseLibcouchbaseException' with message 'Failed to create libcouchbase instance' in /tmp/test.php:3
```

how should i fix this problem?

Comment: How did you install it? Use apt in ubuntu, it will take care of most things for you

Comment: What user is running the script? That user will need the same `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable

Comment: @Phil - i ran `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/couchbase/lib` with my user. should i have also run it with user `couchbase`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i took eddie's advice and reinstalled using `apt`. now everything works fine:

```
sudo wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase-ubuntu1204.list
wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcouchbase{2,-dev,-dbg}
```

Comment: you can also use .deb files (when you cannot use apt), just make sure you will resolve dependencies, because backends depend on event libraries (libevent, libev), which likely not installed in the system (/usr/lib). You can install them manually before using .deb distributions (apt-get install libevent) and everything will be ok.

Comment: this answer was thanks to @avsej on freenode irc channel #libcouchbase